# What printed materials from Avatar: The Last Airbender are canonical?

Tags: canon, the-legend-of-korra, avatar-the-last-airbender

What printed materials from the Avatar universe are considered canon?

Here's a quick list of what I've seen out there:

- The Promise (Parts 1, 2, 3)
- The Lost Adventures
- The Lost Scrolls (Air, Water, Fire, Earth)
- The Search (Forthcoming)

There might be more. So, what's what?

Comment: @Keen Are you looking for the more comprehensive list or the most detailed?

Comment: @Pureferret Just a comprehensive list with citations of their canon-ness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very few stories where the canonicity can be confirmed, I can't even tell which of those in the bottom section Michael and Bryan have even read.

#### [The Promise](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Promise)<sup>[1](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Promise_Part_1),[2](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Promise_Part_2),[3](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Promise_Part_3)</sup>

From the Wikia

> In late 2010, Samantha Robertson, an editor at Dark Horse Comics at the time, approached comic author Gene Yang, who was best known for his American-Born Chinese series. After "some conversations" with her and the creators of Avatar, Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko, Yang was contracted to write three graphic novels to serve as a direct sequel to the original series.

This is revealed in an [interview](http://avatarthelastairbenderonline.com/avatar-the-promise-part-1/) with the Gene Yang:

> **AvatarTheLastAirbenderOnline.com** – What role are Mike and Bryan playing in the project? Are they co-authors etc..? (How much are they playing a part?)
>
> **Gene Yang** – Mike and Bryan have been involved from the very beginning. We had a couple of phone conversations where they gave me ideas that eventually made it into the scripts. *They’ve read over every outline and every script that I’ve written*. They give me notes on how to get the comic to feel more like the show. Working with them is one of the best parts about this project. They and their entire crew are consummate storytellers. I’ve learned a lot by hearing how they think through a story.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

I would surmise from that, and the fact that this trilogy directly leads up to the formation of Republic City, *this is canon*.

---

#### [The Last Airbender comics](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender_comics)

All but two of these (*[Gym Time](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender_comics#Gym_Time)* and *[New Recruits](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender_comics#New_Recruits)*) are considered [canon](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender_comics). This is because they are all publications endorsed by Nickelodeon. *New Recruit* is listed as a 'bonus story' which is what casts doubts on it's canonicity, as well as the characters being fan created. *Gym time* features a dead avatar and various enemies, and thus does not fit in canon (it is similar to the bonus material on the DVDs featuring valentines day, and [chibi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chibi_%28term%29) characters.)

---

#### [Sozin's Comet](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Sozin%27s_Comet:_The_Final_Battle)

This is a novelization of the last four episodes of the series, as such they are *literally* canon with the show as far as I can tell

---

### Other material of dubious canonicity:

#### Chapter books

Lost Scrolls
The Earth Kingdom Chronicles
Ready-to-Read Series

#### Movie novelizations

*The Last Airbender Movie Novelization
Aang's Destiny
Battle of the North
Trial by Fire
The Avatar's Return*

#### Trivia and games

The Ultimate Pocket Guide
Brainbenders for the Four Nations
Mindbenders and Brainbusters: The Ultimate Avatar Challenge
The Avatar's Return

#### Graphic novels/comic books

Tokyopop Cine-Manga
"Private Fire"
The Last Airbender movie tie-ins
The Lost Adventures
~The Search
Avatar: The Last Airbender — The Art of the Animated Series

Italics indicate items that definitely do not share cartoon canonicity, ~ items are yet to be released.

Answer (score 2):

The latest on this seems to be:

**Novels**

A set of two novels about Kyoshi, written by F. C. Yee and Avatar co-creator Michael Dante DiMartino is listed as co-writer for both

1. [The Rise of Kyoshi](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rise_of_Kyoshi) (published 2019)
2. [The Shadow of Kyoshi](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/The_Shadow_of_Kyoshi) (published 2020)

**Graphic Novels**

The Dark Horse comics all have Bryke (Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko) credited as co-writers/collaborators and events of these graphic novels were corroborated by events seen in Korra. The Search was even based on a initial TV-movie script for a sequel. Hence there is no reason to believe these aren't meant to be canon by the PTB

1. [The Promise trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/The_Promise) by Gene Luen Yang, with art by Gurihiru (first published 2012).
2. [The Search trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/The_Search) by Gene Luen Yang, with art by Gurihiru (first published 2013).
3. [The Rift trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rift) by Gene Luen Yang, with art by Gurihiru (first published 2014).
4. [The Smoke and Shadow trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Smoke_and_Shadow) by Gene Luen Yang, with art by Gurihiru (first published 2015-2016).
5. [North and South trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/North_and_South) by Gene Luen Yang, with art by Gurihiru (first published 2016-2017).
6. [Imbalance trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Imbalance) by Faith Erin Hicks with art by Peter Wartman and Adele Matera. (first published 2018-2019)
7. "Awesome Ladies" trilogy of standalone graphic novels by Faith Erin Hicks and Tim Hendricks with art by Peter Wartman and Adele Matera. However, unlike the rest of the novels in this list, these three *do not* list Bryke as collaborators/co-writers.

   - [Katara and the Pirate's Silver](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Katara_and_the_Pirate%27s_Silver) (first published 2020).
   - [Toph Beifong's Metalbending Academy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Toph_Beifong%27s_Metalbending_Academy) (first published 2021).
   - [Suki, Alone](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Suki,_Alone#Trivia) (first published 2021).

**Graphic Novels actually written by Bryke**
While Bryke are listed as co-writers/collaborators for a bunch of the graphic novels above, they are the sole/main listed writers for many of the Korra comics out. Hence these could potentially be considered "more canon" than the others

1. [Friends for Life](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Friends_for_Life) (first published 2016) Story: Michael Dante DiMartino; Art: Heather Campbell and Killian Ng
2. [Turf Wars trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Turf_Wars). (first published 2017) Story: Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko; Art and color: Irene Koh, Killian Ng, and Jane Bak
3. [Lost Pets](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Lost_Pets) (first published 2018) Story: Michael Dante DiMartino; Art: Jayd Aït-Kaci and Killian Ng
4. [Ruins of the Empire trilogy](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Ruins_of_the_Empire) (first published 2019). Story: Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko; Art and color: Michelle Wong and Killian Ng

**Comics Anthologies**

1. [The Lost Adventures](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lost_Adventures) (first collected in 2011) is "*is an anthology of comics collecting previously unpublished comics, minicomics included as part of the Book Two: Earth and Book Three: Fire DVD volumes, the Avatar comic from Free Comic Book Day 2011, and the numerous works released by Nickelodeon Magazine and Nickelodeon Comics Club from 2005 through 2009. The first twenty-six comics included occur in between episodes of the first series, while the last two are non-canonical stories.*" Bryan is listed as the artist for the cover, but none of the stories list them as co-writers. However, some of the stories are written by episode writers.
2. [Team Avatar Tales](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Team_Avatar_Tales) (first collected in 2020) doesn't seem to have any statements re:canonicity or not but also have no involvement from Bryke listed anywhere/

Note: this answer only mentions "new" stories of potentially canonical nature, and not published material which is a direct retelling of events seen in the shows.

Comment: It looks like this might be missing some of the material in the existing accepted answer? Let me know if I'm wrong though

Answer (score 0):

The following list is currently all the official Nick-endorsed printed material for the Avatar universe:

**Books**:

- Lost Scrolls
- The Earth Kingdom Chronicles
- Sozin's Comet: The Final Battle
- Ready-to-Read Series

**(Movie Novelizations)**:

- The Last Airbender Movie Novelization
- Aang's Destiny
- Battle of the North
- Trial by Fire
- The Avatar's Return

**Graphic Novels/Comic Books**:

- Tokyopop Cine-Manga
- ["Private Fire"](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Private_Fire)
- The Last Airbender movie tie-ins
- The Lost Adventures
- The Promise
- The Search
- [Avatar the Last Airbender: Official Comic](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar%3a_The_Last_Airbender_comics)

Source: [Avatar Wiki: List of Avatar: The Last Airbender books](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar%3a_The_Last_Airbender_books)

There is no indication anywhere to the lack of canon-status, with the exception of the Movie novelizations which follow an alternate canon (that we should politely ignore).

The Cine-manga is [described as](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyopop_Cine-Manga):

> a series of graphic novels that take screencaps and dialogue from the animated series from "The Boy in the Iceberg" to the "Winter Solstice Part 2: Avatar Roku".

And the Official Comic is printed by Nick as shown in the attribution on the Avatar wiki.